# best way to get products by storeviews

Tags: php, magento, magento2

That's my doubt. I have to export one XML file for each storeview on a magento hosting. This catalog has to contain all products available by storeview. The info that i need to export is at least: SKU, name, description,images url, categories which each product belongs and products URL. 
I already have done the logic, but I am having problems with filtering the products, what I am doing now it's :

```
public function getXmlForAllStores()
  {

    foreach ($this->_storeManagerInterface->getWebsites() as $site):{
      foreach ($site->getGroups() as $store): {
        $rootCategoryId  = $store->getRootCategoryId();
        $rootCategory = $this->_rootCategory->load($rootCategoryId);
        $catIdArray = $this->toIntArray($rootCategory->getAllChildren(true));
        foreach ($store->getStores() as $storeview):{$collection = $this->_categoryLayer
          ->setCurrentCategory($rootCategory)
          ->getProductCollection()
          ->addWebsiteFilter($site);
          //get xml string
          $xmlData= $this->toXml($collection, $store, $storeview);
          $fileName = $storeview->getCode()."feed.xml";
          echo "filename: ". $fileName. "<br>";
          //make file
          $this->makeFile($xmlData,$fileName);


        }endforeach;
      }endforeach;
    }endforeach;
    return "ok";
  }
```

as you can see, i am iterating on lowest scope to get different xml files for all storeviews on all stores-group contained on each website. but i can't find the way to retrieve data according the storeview, like name, description and more critical, the product url according the storeview.
the setstoreid filter doesn't work for what i want.
any help would be great, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is already available by default in Magento. For getting products for a particular store view, do the following:

Go to your Catalog > Products

Select a store view above the product list.

You are now viewing all products included in this store view.

Once you have the correct store view selected, select the products you want to Enable or Disable using the checkbox on the left.

Now, using the Actions dropdown menu on top right of the product list, choose 'Change Status', select 'Disabled' or 'Enabled' and hit the Submit button.

Comment: Can be, but if I am asking it's because the needed of making this programmatically. And I think "select status" it's a global attribute. Thanks for watching.